# Open bluetooth settings on iOS 14.5 with react-native 0.64.1

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm trying to open the Bluetooth settings in iOS 14.5 with react-native 0.64.1,

so I've tried few options,

`Linking.openURL('App-prefs:Bluetooth');`

`Linking.openURL('App-prefs:root=Bluetooth');`

`Linking.openURL('App-prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth');`

none of these options is not working in iOS 14.5,
they just open the settings, without getting into the Bluetooth settings.

is this possible to achieve the application to open the Bluetooth settings in iOS 14.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no supported way to do that.

Even if you do find one, your app will likely be rejected for use of private APIs.